# UIPickerView will not display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am trying to create a `PickerView` view programatically.

I have followed all of the necessary steps however the picker just simply appears and then disappears straight away. No data can be seen.

I am setting the delegate and data source and I have implemented the necessary methods. 
Here is my code:

**in .h**

```
@interface NJATimeEntryViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *customerPicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pickerTitles;

@end
```

**in .m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pickerTitles = @[@"ONE", @"TWO", @"THREE"];

    self.customerPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
    self.customerPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.customerPicker.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.customerPicker];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.pickerTitles.count;
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[self pickerTitles] objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"Selected Row %d", row);
}
```

All help is appreciated thanks.

**FIXED:**

All i did was set the background color of the view controllers view and now it works. I see this as a bug as no where is it stated that the background color has to be set.

Comment: Is customerPicker declared as a strong pointer?

Comment: @daniele: it is not matter about `strong` or `weak`.

Comment: @daniele Yep it is :)

Comment: @leewaa: are doing something else,? because  this code looks gud.

Comment: How is `pickerTitles` declared? Could you post your .h?

Comment: @Virussmca Nah I just have the implementation for the Picker.

Comment: I have checked your code, its working perfectly.

Comment: Just updated my question with the .h code

I don't get it that is exactly what I have and it just appears and then disappears.

Comment: set some background color of view, and upload snap of it.

Comment: just set the background color and now it works THANKS.

I can't believe that this is not stated anywhere that if the background color is not set that the picker will not appear.

Comment: @leewaa: if i write it as answer would you like to accept it.?

Comment: Yeah sure, however take note. if I set the background color to black then the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Some Background color ( except black )of your view, then try,

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
```